# Instantiating BSD jails from C

Tags: c, freebsd, jail

I have been trying to be able to create BSD jails from an application.  Based on the FreeBSD man pages for [jail(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jail&sektion=2) I've come up with:

```
struct jail _jail;
_jail->version = <jail version>;
_jail->path = "/some/path/";
_jail->hostname = "some-host";
_jail->jailname = "jailname";
_jail->ip4s = <ip value>;
_jail->ip6s = <ip value>;
_jail->ip4 = <ip4 struct>;
_jail->ip6 = <ip6 struct>;
int jid = jail(&jail);
```

So from this, I was wondering what example values for the ip4, and ip6 fields would look like?  Additionally what tool(s) can I use to inspect the jail to ensure that I instantiated them properly? (I'm traditionally a Linux user, so this is uncharted territory for me).

To clarify the fields question, I understand what the in_addr type is in Linux, can I assume it is the same for FreeBSD?

Comment: actually ip4s and ip6s are the counts of ip4 and ip6 structures you pass.. It's actually very well described in the jail(2) man page.

Comment: @AhmedMasud That's not what I'm asking, as I said in my edit, I am asking if I can assume the in_addr is the same from Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by "inspect the jail to ensure that I instantiated them properly?"?

Comment: I mean a tool that allows me to see the process(es), user and fs within the jail.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski `jexec ps` and `jexec ls /`?

Comment: @arrowd Thanks, that works perfectly, mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run arbitrary command in the jail use [jexec](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jexec&sektion=8):

```
jexec jail ls
jexec jail ps
```

You can also run a shell inside jail:

```
jexec jail csh
```

Or even

```
jexec jail env -i TERM=$TERM /usr/bin/login -fp root
```